# dataframe append new series column with data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Panda DataFrame structure and I want to add another column to it, but I can't do it with append, add or insert.

I'm trying to replicate the portfolio data with the Panda's built-in function, because this script doesn't give me correct data if the period that I request is lower than ~ 1,5 years while data must be obtained even for two days if I want. So here's the script that I want to rewrite:

```
import QSTK.qstkutil.qsdateutil as du
import QSTK.qstkutil.tsutil as tsu
import QSTK.qstkutil.DataAccess as da

import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

ls_symbols = ["AAPL", "GLD", "GOOG", "$SPX", "XOM"]
dt_start = dt.datetime(2006, 1, 1)
dt_end = dt.datetime(2010, 12, 31)
dt_timeofday = dt.timedelta(hours=16)
ldt_timestamps = du.getNYSEdays(dt_start, dt_end, dt_timeofday)

c_dataobj = da.DataAccess('Yahoo')
ls_keys = ['open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume', 'actual_close']
ldf_data = c_dataobj.get_data(ldt_timestamps, ls_symbols, ls_keys)
**d_data = dict(zip(ls_keys, ldf_data))**
```

`d_data = dict(zip(ls_keys, ldf_data))` is what I want to replicate because it doesn't fetch the data that I want, but I need to figure out a way to append a new column to my dict. Here is my script:

```
from pandas.io.data import DataReader, DataFrame
import QSTK.qstkutil.qsdateutil as du
import QSTK.qstkutil.DataAccess as da

import datetime as dt

def get_historical_data(symbol, source, date_from, date_to):
    global data_validator
    symbol_data = {}

    ls_keys = ['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Adj Close']

    for key in ls_keys:
        symbol_data[key] = DataFrame({})

    dataframe_open = DataFrame({})

    for item in symbol:
        print 'Fetching data for:', item
        current_data = DataReader(str(item), source, date_from, date_to)
        dataframe_open = {item : current_data['Open']}
        if len(symbol_data['Open'].columns) == 0:
            symbol_data['Open'] = DataFrame(dataframe_open)
        else:
            **#i want to add the new column here but can't seem to do this.**
            #symbol_data['Open'].loc[:item] = DataFrame(dataframe_open)
            pass
    return symbol_data
```

P.S. I call the func with these parameters for testing purposes:

`test = get_historical_data(['SPY', 'DIA'], 'yahoo', datetime(2015,1,1), datetime(2015,1,31))`

Answer (score 0):

Does the following help? Have not tested yet, but should work in principle... Just put the data in arrays of equal length and construct the data frame from that.

```
def get_historical_data(symbols=[], source=None, date_from=None, date_to=None):
    global data_validator
    symbol_data = {}

    ls_keys = ['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Adj Close']
    data = []
    for item in ls_keys:
        data.append(DataReader(str(item), source, date_from, date_to)
    symbol_dataframe=DataFrame(data=data, columns=ls_keys)
    #symbol_dataframe = DataFrame()
    #for key in ls_keys:
    #    symbol_data[key] = DataFrame({})

    #dataframe_open = DataFrame({})

    #for item in symbols:
    '''    print 'Fetching data for:', item
        current_data = DataReader(str(item), source, date_from, date_to)
        dataframe_open = {item : current_data['Open']}
        #print(dataframe_open)
        if len(symbol_data['Open'].columns) == 0:
            symbol_data['Open'] = DataFrame(dataframe_open)
        else:
            #i want to add the new column here but can't seem to do this.**
            symbol_data['Open'] = DataFrame(dataframe_open)
            symbol_data.head()
    '''
    return symbol_dataframe
```

Comment: Thanks, i saw your post too late. Maybe it works, but I made a workaround to actually first design the DataFrame, and then programatically populate the data in all columns and in this way I escaped the need to append the new column.